# WPF Combobox Setting Visual Style Stroke

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

So I made my own class called `ComboBoxUltra` and it inherits from `ComboBox` in `System.Windows.Controls`.

I am re-templating it and need help on how can I set the `Stroke` value on the `Rectangle` of the `FocusVisualStyle`  to a new `DependencyProperty` with in the `ComboBoxUltra`.

This is what I have and it does not work. I have the other stuff defined if need be to post it on here... But its quite lengthy.

In Xaml I have:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                               Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:ComboBoxPro}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=FocusedBorderBrush}"
                               StrokeThickness="1" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:ComboBoxUltra}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusVisual}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3,5,3" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both" />
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}" />

        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource TextFontSizeNormal}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

And in my `ComboBoxUltra` class I have the `DependencyProperty` as...

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusedBorderBrushProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(FocusedBorderBrush), typeof(Brush), typeof(ComboBoxUltra),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Orange, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
        public Brush FocusedBorderBrush
        {
            get => (Brush)GetValue(FocusedBorderBrushProperty);
            set => SetValue(FocusedBorderBrushProperty, value);
        }
```

I've tried removing the `FocusVisualStyle` And just do a `Trigger` on `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`, and set the border brush with a setter but that did not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't bind to a property of the ComboBox in the FocusVisualStyle since it is displayed on the adorned layer. The trigger approach is the correct one.

Comment: @mm8  when I do that though it isn't showing.. Because the FocusVisualStyle is showing above it.

Comment: Did you try to set the `FocusVisualStyle` property to `null`?

Comment: @mm8  Yeah sorry I got it fixed now thanks so much!  I kept the focus visual style but changed that `Stroke` to `Transparent`  and then put the `Trigger` back on the style.  Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind to a property of the `ComboBox` in the `FocusVisualStyle` since it is displayed on the adorned layer.

The trigger approach that you have tried is the correct one. Just remember to set the `FocusVisualStyle` property to `null`, or set the `Stroke` property of the `Rectangle` to `Transparent` to get rid of it.